# Kendo multi select component passing placeholder as value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I have a form with a **Kendo UI MultiSelec**t component for **ASP.NET MVC / Razor**:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.Ids)
                .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
                .AutoBind(true)
                .MinLength(3)
                .Delay(500)
                .DataTextField("Value")
                .DataValueField("Key")
                .Placeholder("Please fill")
                .DataSource(
                    ds => ds.Read(
                        r => r.Action("FillMultiSelect", "ReportsController", new { companyId = IdentityManager.CompanyID, search = string.Empty })
                        ).ServerFiltering(true)
                )
            )
```

JavaScript for filtering:

```
var $ids = $("#Ids").data("kendoMultiSelect");

$ids.dataSource.transport.options.read.data = basicFilter($ids);

var basicFilter = function ($element) {
   return {
       companyId: self.form.getModel().CompanyId,
       search: $element.input.val()
   }
}
```

When I type the search text at the "Ids" MultiSelect, the parameter passed to the ASP.NET MVC **Action** is the value of the **placeholder** of the element:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Obs.: I'm testing with Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors was in retrieving value from `MultiSelect` component. I should use the `filters` array from `filter` object, passed by the `data` event. Correct JavaScript:

window.global.setDatasourceTransportFilter($("#Ids"), "kendoMultiSelect", basicFilter);

```
var basicFilter = function (e) {
   return {
       companyId: self.form.getModel().CompanyId,
       search: e.filter && e.filter.filters[0] ? e.filter.filters[0].value : ""
   }
}
```